# How to convert string containing variable content to JSON

Tags: c#, json, type-conversion

I am already using [JsonSerializer](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer.htm) of [Newtonesoft Package](https://www.newtonsoft.com/) to convert strings to JSON format ,but it can't convert this string to JSON.

```
{
    "isSuccess": true,
    "elapsed": 54,
    "results": {
        "131351990802396920": "updated",
        "21034623651844830": "updated",
        "112201011402879160": "updated"
    },
    "errors": {
    "105933291602523100": "Error",
    "106574790922078090": "Error",
    "114439941021395940": "Error",
    "123574814601457710": "Error"
    }
}
```

The Class structure that i am trying to convert string to, is as follows:

```
public class UpdateResultSt
{
    public bool isSuccess { get; set; }
    public int elapsed { get; set; }

    public List<SuccessfulUpdateResult> results = new List<SuccessfulUpdateResult>();
    public List<FailedUpdateResult> errors = new List<FailedUpdateResult>();
}
public class SuccessfulUpdateResult
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
}
public class FailedUpdateResult
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
}
```

This is some of my code which is responsible for converting:

```
    JsonSerializer json_serializer;
    json_serializer = new JsonSerializer
    {
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
    };
    JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(responseFromServer));
    UpdateResultSt routes_list = json_serializer.Deserialize<UpdateResultSt>(jsonReader);
```

As you see both `the Results` and `the Errors` scopes have variable content.

There are some other questions with the same issue but no one could resolve my problem. The error message is :

> 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
>   into type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ConceptTaggerWinApp.UpdateResultSt]'
>   because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
>   correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array
>   (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal
>   .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection
>   type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON
>   object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it
>   to deserialize from a JSON object. Path 'isSuccess', line 1, position
>   13.'

How do I change my classes structure to convert this string to JSON sucessfully?

Comment: What's the error message you're getting?

Comment: Shouldn't `{}` in `results` and `errors` be `[]`?

Comment: @Rafalon I am not able to change string because it comes from a web service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can't change the Json's format, I'd say the following class should work as expected:

```
public class UpdateResultSt
{
    public bool isSuccess { get; set; }
    public int elapsed { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string,string> results { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string,string> errors { get; set; }
}
```

You could then write something like:

```
routes_list.results["131351990802396920"]
```

to get the text `"updated"`.

Or `routes_list.results.Keys` to get the list of the `id`s of the `results`.

See [Deserializing dictionnaries](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingCollections.htm#DeserializingDictionaries).

Answer (score 1):

The format of SuccessfulUpdateResult and FailedUpdateResult are not correct.

It should be like this:

```
{
    "isSuccess": true,
    "elapsed": 54,
    "results": [
        0: { "id" : "131351990802396920", "text" : "updated"},
        1: { "id" :"21034623651844830", "text" : "updated"},
        2: { "id" :"112201011402879160", "text" : "updated"}
    ],
    "errors": {
     // same than SuccessfulUpdateResult 
     ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your json string doesn't represent the object graph your trying to deserialise it into.
your outer class should have an array or results and an array or errors similar to this:

```
{
"isSuccess": true,
"elapsed": 54,
"results": [
    {"id":"131351990802396920", "test":"updated"},
    {"id":"21034623651844830","text":"updated"},
    {"id":"112201011402879160", "text":"updated"}
],
"errors": [
{"id":"105933291602523100","test":"Error"},
{"id":"106574790922078090","text":"Error"},
{"id":"114439941021395940","text":"Error"},
{"id":"123574814601457710","text":"Error"}
]
```

}

what you have is one result class with three fields called 131351990802396920, 21034623651844830, 112201011402879160 so it cant map it to your objects.

Comment: As said in the comments below OP's question, he has no control over the Json string. And the question clearly is "*How do I **change my classes structure** to convert this string to JSON sucessfully?*"